# if rule returning wrong result in PHP

Tags: php

Good morning.

I am running a small test on a for a future website built on PHP 7.

I want the web page to record the user login name in the superglobal array SESSION, then,

if the user enters a login name, the page should show a link to the forums

if the user does not provide any login name but presses the submit button, the scrip should show a link directing to the home page.

The action page is the same one as the page showing the form.

This is the php part of the code :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['loginName']))
    {       
        $_SESSION['loginName'] = $_POST['loginName'];
        echo 'Login name is : '.$_SESSION['loginName'];
        echo '<a href="accessForum.php">Get to the forum !</a>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'No name provided. Try again or move back to <a href="index.php">homepage</a>';
    }
?>
```

The problem : when I press the submit button without entering a login name, the else statements do not apply. Instead, the if statements apply and show an empty string after 'Login name is'.

I don't understand the why of this behaviour. Can anyone help ? Thankyou, Christopho.

Comment: Please, sorry for the orthograhic mistakes, and don't mind the visual outup of such a code (no space between text and links) : it's just for testing purposes. Thankyou !

Comment: if(isset($_POST['loginName']) && $_POST['loginName'] != "" )

Comment: also there is a missing session_start();

Comment: @vp_arth There's a shorthand for that: `!empty($_POST['loginName'])`. The caveat in both cases is that `"0"` won't pass that test; which may be undesired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a form, the form field will be submitted to the server, even if it contains no data (an empty string). `isset` will only tell you whether the form field was submitted at all, which it is. You need to check yourself whether the name contains any content, e.g. with `strlen($_POST['loginName']) > 0`.

Comment: This is correct (though you could also use `if(empty($var))` or simply `if($var)`). However, you should check `isset()` *as well* as checking whether the content is empty, as it is possible for your page to be called without the form contents being posted -- eg if someone tried to directly access the URL for your post page.

Comment: @Simba You don't need to check `isset()` _and_ `empty()`. `empty()` itself checks whether it `isset()`.